# Size of font in CSS with slash

Tags: html, css, size

What does the slash mean here:

```
font: 100%/120%;
```

Comment: `font-size` does not accept the slash. The correct property is `font`.

Comment: how about these?

background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box"

Answer (score 212, accepted):

This actually sets two properties and is equivalent to:

```
font-size: 100%;
line-height: 120%;
```

To quote the [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font):

> The syntax of this property is based on a traditional typographical shorthand notation to set multiple properties related to fonts.

As David M said in the comments, it mirrors the typesetting tradition of specifying typeface sizes as “*x* pt on *y* pt” to denote the glyph size on line height.

But the example in your question is actually wrong and would be ignored by the browser: you can only combine these two properties in the `font` shorthand notation, and you *must* specify at least both the font size and family. Simply writing `font: 100%/120%;` is therefore not enough; you could add a generic family name to make it valid though, e.g.:

```
font: 100%/120% serif;
```

Comment: It's to mirror old typesetting syntax, where you'd have font set as, for instance "10pt on 12pt", or "10pt/12pt".

Comment: I actually use this quite a bit. The designer I work with always refers to sizing as, for example, "14 over 22". I put it in by accident one day and was surprised/content when it worked.

Comment: a quickie: does this format also not require the font-family to be specified? My browsers are ignoring this property:

    font: 12px/16px;

but accepting this:

    font: 12px/16px sans-serif;

This behaviour is also documented [here](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-shorthand-properties.shtml)

Comment: @Harsh Yes, a family (along with a size) is minimally required for the `font` shorthand property as you can see in the [official definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Perhaps you can update the answer (or the question) as it is slightly misleading in that a casual reader can assume that only a SIZE/LINE_HEIGHT declaration would work.

Answer (score 15):

Konrad got this one, but there are a lot of [CSS shorthand](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-shorthand-properties.shtml) properties like this that you can use to shorten your style sheets.  Some of them look a little cryptic if you're not aware of them.

Comment: Most shorthands address related style properties, though (e.g. `border-*`). David has given a good explanation in the comments to my answer. As to shorthands being cryptic: certainly true, but so damn useful and quite easy to learn.