# What does the '/' symbol mean in CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size in CSS with slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701732/size-in-css-with-slash)

I just saw some CSS code like this. Can some please tell me what the '/' symbol means and if there are any best practices governing it's usage ?

```
font: 2px/3px;
```

**Edit:**

Here is the entire code block (to give context)

```
.funky {
  font: 2px/3px;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 30em;
    font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In that example it means `font-size:2px`,and `line-height:3px`. Although I am not sure if that works without the rest of the font rule. 
http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/

Comment: It works - it just happens to reset every other property to default, so be very careful when using just these 2 values alone with `font`.