# Inexplicable HTML/CSS behaviour

Tags: html, css

I have a **simple html** page with a rather **simple css**, and it drives me nuts - I do *not at all understand what is happening here* (the original task is to create a simple contact form, using modernizr, but I have stripped everything down):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 26px;
        }

        label {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        input {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: 4px;
        }

        input:focus {
            border: 2px solid #900;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <label>1:</label><input id="1" /><br />
    <label>2:</label><input id="2" /><br />
    <label>3:</label><input id="3" /><br />

</body>
</html>
```

The three rows with the labels and the input boxes have increasing left margins, and if I set the focus to any input, the ones below jump back (at least in Chrome and FF). **Why?**

Now, if I remove virtually ***any*** css property, things get stranger:

1. The original above can be found [here](http://www.schreiberx.de/stackoverflow/weird_html_css_everything_in.html).
2. If I remove the the *body* line **(or even only the *line-height: 26px;* part!!**), the left margin disappears (why?), check [here](http://www.schreiberx.de/stackoverflow/weird_html_css_no_body.html).
3. If I remove the *input:focus* line, the jump doesn't happen anymore (why?), check [here](http://www.schreiberx.de/stackoverflow/weird_html_css_no_focus.html).
4. If I remove *border: 1px solid #ccc;* from *input*, the margins are gone (why???), check [here](http://www.schreiberx.de/stackoverflow/weird_html_css_no_input_border.html).

And there are other interdependencies as well. This doesn't happen in jsfiddle and other online tools but can be easily reproduced locally.

**Bottom line: the whole behavior seems completely alien to me, and I hope a CSS Sherlock Holmes can shed some light on what happens here.**

Comment: I would recommend using `<ul>` and `<li>` for a contact form, rather than lots of `<br />`, this will both fix the problem and make your page more semantic

Comment: @Andy, thanks, true, but still I'd like to understand the strange behaviour of my html/css.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `font: 16px/26px Arial;` ? I don't understand the 16px/26px part.

Comment: @Magus [size-in-css-with-slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701732/size-in-css-with-slash)

Comment: Remove the 2px instead of 1px on the focus. it fixes your problem, it has to do with spacing between the items.

Comment: @Magus: I have changed this to two lines.

Comment: Both answers - br {clear: both;} as well as the line height explanation - make sense (which makes it hard to choose a winner). Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the numbered list.

You are setting a margin-top, and making the line height bigger than the text itself. This is normally fine but this makes the numbers bigger than the input boxes.

You are forcing a new line with `<br />` and they can't naturally float to where they should be, as the previous number is "too large" for its "line".

I'm struggling to explain it, but to fix it you can add `line-height: 2;` to the input boxes, or any of the fixes you mentioned, or better yet replace it all with an ordered list.

If you still don't understand, try setting `border: 1px solid #000;` on the labels, you will see what I mean.

Comment: You are right! I got it. I will definitely use a list, but I feel relieved because it's making sense now.

Answer (score 2):

The unexpected behavior is because the `labels` are acting in the same `float` context, with no `clear` breaking it. So when you tell your second `label` to `float` to the left, it find the previous label, and thus "stacks" to the right.

Add the following to your CSS (if you insist on using `br` tags):

```
br {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: And it stacks beneath the `input`/`br` and not to the right of it because the `input`/`br` are inline.

Comment: This works and makes sense. But still I'd like to know why removing *line-height: 26px;* sort of fixes this. Is it maybe a combination of spacing and float issues?