# What do these CSS font properties mean?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I grabbed some CSS from a website and while I have a pretty good understanding of basic CSS I don't understand all of the styles/properties here:

```
font: normal normal bold 36px/54px brandon-grotesque-n7, brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
```

Some additional context - this is CSS for a logo, which you can see in this **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4wmbqes/)**.

Specifically I am curious about:

- Why does it say "normal normal bold"?
- Why is there a slash on the font-size?
- Why are there three font types listed?

Comment: What part don't you understand? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font

Comment: Just updated with specific questions.

Comment: [The slash meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701732/size-in-css-with-slash)

Comment: `brandon-grotesque-n7, brandon-grotesque, sans-serif` means that the first typeface choice is `brandon-grotesque-n7`, if unavailable then choose `brandon-grotesque` if all else fails, use the default browser `sans-serif` typeface.

Comment: @misterManSam cool, thx for info...that's 2/3 down

Comment: The slash between font size is `line-height`. So it's 36px font size and 54px leading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is a shorthand font declaration. It is essentially the same as writing the following:

```
font-family: brandon-grotesque-n7, brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 54px;
```

**Why does it say "normal normal bold"?**

This is font-style, followed by font-variant, followed by font-weight. Another example would be something like `italic small-caps bold`.

**Why is there a slash on the font-size?**

This is font-size followed by line-height. In your example, the font-size is 36px and the line-height is 54px.

**Why are there three font types listed?**

This is called a font stack. The browser will attempt to use those fonts in the order that they are written. If `brandon-grotesque-n7` is unavailable on the user's system, the browser will fall back to using `brandon-grotesque`. If that is unavailable, it will use the system's default `sans-serif` font.

A helpful cheat sheet for font shorthand:
[image]

Cheat sheet source: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

Just so this question has an answer not in comments. From [CSS-Tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/):

**CSS**
`font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;`

**USE**
`font: italic small-caps normal 13px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`