# Issue with 'em' value in CSS

Tags: css

CSS

```
font-size: 1.1em/1.5;
```

what does 1.1em/1.5 mean in CSS.  I am familiar with 'em' property in CSS but why are we dividing with some number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you define

`font: 1.1em/1.5 ...` ;

you're using a shorthand property where the first value is the `font-size` and the second value is the `line-height` (which can be also unitless)

Comment: upvote from me as this was the correct answer and the first to be posted.

Comment: Oh well, that's new to me. Why do they use a a slash to seperate values? Other shorthands don't use anything (e.g `padding: 1rem 0.5rem;`).

Comment: upvote from me too but my reputation is less than 15:)

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing, since the declaration `font-size: 1.1em/1.5` is syntactically malformed and browsers are required to ignore it.

A declaration like `font: 1.1em/1.5 serif` would be a different matter. But regarding the meaning of `/1.5` there, it has already been answered e.g. here: [Size of font in CSS with slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701732/size-in-css-with-slash).

Answer (score 0):

If `font` has two values separated by slash, the first one means `font-size`, the second one `line-height`.

Ex.
If parent has `font-size 10px`, this element will have `font-size 11px` and `line-height 16.5px` (11 * 1.5).

Comment: `font-size` doesn't accept multiple values, nor slash. Therefore it would be ignored by the browser.